# dev c++ printf error in console

Tags: c, printf, dev-c++

I'm using dev c++ 5.11 from orwell to get some schoolwork, but when i run the code inside the program it wont show the printf("contenido de la matriz") everything else runs well, and something funny is that the program does run well outside of dev c++, i mean the .exe file in my computer will show the printf, and when i save the code to an empty folder i can see my progress inside of dev, but when the file is with many other .cpp programs then it doesn't run inside dev c++, but i do want to be able to see my progress in dev what should i do i wouldn't like to create a folder for everyprogram i made.

here's the code if you want to try it on dev. thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    int main ()
    {
             int i,j,col,lin;
             int x[6][5]={{0,1,2,3,4}, // primero ponemos el numero de linea y luego el numero de columna
                     {5,6,7,8,9},
                     {10,11,12,13,14},
                     {15,16,17,18,19},
                     {20,21,22,23,24},
                     {25,26,27,28,29}};
    col=5; lin=8; //posición del contenido de la matriz
    gotoxy(5,6); //nos posicionamos en la col 5 y linea 7 y damos un printf: contenido de la matriz
    printf("contenido de la matriz");
    for(i=0; i<=5; i++){ //en este caso es <=5 ya que en i=6 pero como empieza a contar desde el 0 y no 1 entonces por eso es 5 i=numero de linea
             for(j=0; j<=4; j++){ //ciclo anhidado j=5 y es lo mismo empieza a contar desde 0 j=numero de columna
                      gotoxy(col,lin);
                      printf("%d", x[i][j]);
                      col=col+5; //para que ponga los valores de j espaciados 
                      }
                      col=5;
                      lin++;
                      }
    getch ();
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that is clearly a problem is that your `printf()`s don't have a `'\n'` anywhere so probably the buffers are not being flushed by the IDE output window.

Either add the `'\n'` like

```
printf("Contenido de la Matriz\n");
```

or add an `fflush(stdout);` after every `printf()` statement.

**Note**: And for godness sake format your code as if it was going to be read by humans and not just compilers.

Comment: Hi friend! Thanks for answering but i still get the same output, the printf doesn't show inside of dev c, do you have any other suggestion? and i will make my codes clearer sorry I'm new :( thanks again.

Comment: Then don't use `devc++` use another IDE or even better switch to Linux and install geany and stop suffering.